# Getting tables, primary keys, and then selecting a row

Tags: sql, oracle, select, key

Expanding on a previous question: I'm working with a Oracle database. Here is what I'm doing (or at least what I think I'm doing):

I get all the tables in my database using:

```
select table_name from all_tables
```

Then I get all the primary keys for each table using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM all_cons_columns 
WHERE constraint_name = ( SELECT constraint_name 
FROM all_constraints  WHERE UPPER(table_name) = UPPER('table_name') 
AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P' and rownum<=1)
```

Note: I used distinct and rownum<= 1 since a few of the tables seem to unfortunately have duplicate primary keys (I know that's a problem, but I don't think its the main issue at hand)

Both of the queries seem to be returning what I want; the problem comes when I try to select rows using the table names and primary keys:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE primary_key_column = primary_key_value
```

Depending on which table and key are passed, I get a variety of different errors ranging from ORA-00942: table or view does not exist, ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended, and ORA-00904: "PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN": invalid identifier.

I know I'm doing something wrong, but my lack of experience with all of this is making it hard to figure out what.

Comment: I think you need `execute immediate`.  What you are trying to do requires dynamic SQL.

Comment: Could you explain a little further; possibly provide an example? I'm really new to this and don't fully understand the syntax.

Comment: you are trying to run a query on the table called 'table_name' which doesn't exist, hence the error you are getting. what are you trying to determine with these queries? it looks like you are trying to get a list of all the tables that have primary keys?

Comment: At run time, I replace 'table_name' with an actual table name I got from the first query. What I want to do is get the table names, get the primary keys for each table, and then be able to select rows in a table given the primary key.

Comment: = (subquery) is usually a bit scary, since a subquery may return more than 1 row. That's why I always do IN (subquery) instead.

Comment: you will need to do this with some pl/sql using a for loop that will loop through your query and then run a query for the results that are found

Comment: i posted an answer and then deleted it because i had one more question. what are you basing the primary key value off of in your where statement? I get that you are trying to select all rows in a table that has a primary key but what are you filtering the primary key value to?

Comment: I suppose I don't really know. All I know is that I want to get the tables, get the primary keys in each table, and then be able to find rows in the tables based off those keys. I've kinda just been searching for the correct queries to make that work. I'm not trying to teach myself SQL or databases, I really just need this one aspect to work for a program I'm making in JAVA.

Comment: yeah, i'm failing to grasp what the goal is because the value of the primary key would be stored in the table you are querying and it would be unique for every single record. so getting all the rows in a table based off of a primary key would essentially be the same as running a select * statement on the table. at least with the way you are describing your desired output.

Comment: No no, I want to be able to select a single row of data from a query given the primary key for that row.

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you walked us through an example of exactly what you're doing with one table when you encounter an error.  Show us what you get back from your queries, show us the query you built, show us the error.  My shot in the dark is that you've got some case-sensitive identifiers that you're not accounting for.  I have no idea what you mean when you talk about "duplicate primary keys"-- examples would help.  My shot in the dark, again, is that tables with the same name exist in multiple schemas and your queries are mixing up information about those two different tables.

Comment: So executing through JAVA, I get a list of table names: List<String> tablenames through the result set of "select table_name from all_tables".  Then I want to get the primary keys for all tables, by passing each table name through the middle query posted above. I store those keys in a separate list, and then I map the keys to each table. Now that I have all my table and keys which go with that table, I just want to be able to select an individual row by passing a table name and a primary key to a query. How do I do that?

Comment: you would need to store a distinct list of the primary key values per table and then run your last query based off of that list in order to select a singe row of data

Comment: Could you show us java code ? How do you build the last query?